# getting simple row count with pdo gives error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Just doing a simple row count with pdo and getting a 'Call to a member function query() on a non-object' error.  I'm new to PDO, but this should work perfectly fine... no?  Searching shows the same method being used as correct method.  Maybe I am just that tired?

The session variable is valid.

```
function get_computer_count(){
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM computers WHERE account_id == '".$_SESSION['account']['account_id']."'";
  $results = $db->query($sql);
  $row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
  return $row[0];
}
```

Comment: I wonder if community ever start to close *such* an examplary duplicated questions, instead of snatching some rep points. Never, I guess. Rep is the king. And none of already answered questions or even dedicated reference questions ever do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors.

> Call to a member function query() on a non-object.

**First**, You didn't construct your PDO object.

Like:

```
 $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

**Secondly**, You're most likely to receive an error from the query. The equality comparison in MySQL is not `==` but rather `=`.

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM computers WHERE account_id = '".$_SESSION['account']['account_id']."'
```

As a side not I would recommend not to add apostrophes if `account_id` is not a character field.

Comment: Nope, PDO object is not there

Comment: Whoops, you seem to be right. Anyway, once corrected that error MySQL will complain for the `==` too :)

Comment: Adding the variable correctly and using the correct equality solved it.  Can you explain further about the apos comment? Are you just saying if its not a string to remove the ''s around the SESSION var?

Comment: `As a side not I would recommend not to add apostrophes if account_id is not a character field`: This means if account_id is a string then wrap the value in quotes. If is a number then its fine to have it without quotes

Comment: Right on - thanks guys... time for bed.  Can't believe I missed those two things.

Comment: @user756659 so you are going to add this new PDO thing in your function - right?